# FFMpeg is changing from CFR to VFR on a simple rewrap

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, adobe-premiere, framerate

I'm exporting an x264 MP4 file from Premiere Pro (using Voukoder), then adding subtitles and converting to MKV.  The mp4 output file from Premiere is reported as CFR (by MediaInfo), but after rewrapping, it's reported as VFR.  I am not re-encoding with FFMpeg in any way.
Even this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy video.mkv
```

results in a VFR file.  Now, I understand that this is technically intented behavior, owing to the way FFmpeg calculates its math, but the reality is that using that VFR file in an AVStoDVD project causes issues, whereas the original CFR file did not.

I need a way to rewrap (not re-encode) without changing the durations of any of the frames.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: [This OBS forum thread](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/remuxing-mkv-file-results-in-variable-framerate.93674/) may be worth a look.

Comment: Took a look there, thanks for the suggestion!  That post proposes adding -video_track_timescale 60 right before the output name, but in my case, this still resulted in a (reportedly) VFR file.